# Markov chain and Recurrence

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

We consider a Markov chain $X$ with countable state $F$ and $B$ is a finite subset of $F$ such that for all $x \in S,P_x(T_B<\infty)=1.$ In a proof of a theorem they used this fact to deduce that there exists $y$ such that $P_y(T_y<\infty)=1.$

How to deduce this because in the proof they didn't provide a reason?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the reason for downvoting? The question is concerning a particular part of a proof which isn't comprehensible and this doesn't requires to include an "attempt" since this isn't an exercise, only a missing detail from a proof which requires an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $q_y=P_y(\tau_y<\infty)$ and $p_y=1-q_y$. If $q_y<1$, then the number of visits $N_y$ of the chain to $y$ (when starting at $y$) has a geometric distribution with parameter $p_y$, so  $E_y(N_y)=1/p_y$. Therefore, for all states $x$, we have $E_x(N_y) = 1/p_y$. Write $N_B=\sum_{y \in B} N_y$.
The hypothesis implies that every visit to $B$ will be followed by another one  almost surely, so (iterating and intersecting countably many events of probability 1) we conclude that $P_x(N_B=\infty)=1$ for every initial state $x$.
Now if the inequality $q_y<1$ held for all $y \in B$, we would obtain a contradiction, because
$$E_x(N_B)=\sum_{y \in B} E_x(N_y) \le \sum_{y \in B} 1/p_y \,.$$
Thus there must be some $y \in B$ with $q_y=1$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

You might also find Proposition 21.3 in https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf helpful